# AWS EC2 Wordpress migration running extremely slow and loading incompletely

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up a new EC2 t2.micro instance and I am trying to migrate my Wordpress site over. Here's what I did:

- Created a new volume and copied all my data (including wordpress) to it, mounted at /media/vdc/
- Installed Mysql, Apache2, PHP
- Changed the Apache2 document root to /media/vdc/www/html (this is where my wordpress data is stored)
- Created an elastic IP
- Added define('WP_HOME','http://ip_or_domain.com') 
  and define('WP_SITEURL','http://ip_or_domain.com'); to wp-config.php to stop the site from redirecting to my old domain

Now, the site starts to load but does so *extremely* slowly. I measured the speed and it's about 8 kb/s for each client/server connection. When the site finally does load, it's only basic text, images, etc - no drop down menus or animations.

It's as if the site keeps attempting to load and then eventually times out and just loads the html.

I have two theories:

- t2.micro is too small to handle a wordpress site
- some web technology isn't properly installed like PHP

This is my elastic IP: http://35.155.137.83/

Comment: By allowing traffic from ports 3389 and 443 (in addition to port 80) the website now loads instantly but still incompletely. In addition, logging into wordpress yields a "this site can't be reached" error

Comment: Google dev tools is your friend. It shows connection refused for all your scripts and styles. is your .htaccess file modified at all from the original wordpress one?

Comment: Thank you! I'm realizing that it's trying to access https links when it should be http because I don't have a security cert set up in the new environment. I have tried adding these lines RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE] to my htaccess file but everything else looks normal

Comment: Hey we have all been there my friend. If you have further issues make sure the permissions are correct. You can use this guide to help you. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html#SettingFilePermissions

Comment: In my wp-config I have this line "$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";". I'm thinking this is what is making every style link to be https? However, if I comment it out, or change it to "off", the website doesn't load at all

Comment: What happens when you turn that to off. Also are ports 443 open on your instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168955/discussion-between-saucewagon-and-orlando-p).